# JS Double parenthesis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im not a JS\Front-end dev, but atm i need to explore one of React.JS UI libraries. And i found a strange thing for me.

```
return /*#__PURE__*/(0, _jsxRuntime.jsxs)(TextFieldRoot, (0, _extends2.default)({
    className: (0, _clsx.default)(classes.root, className),
    disabled: disabled,
    error: error,
    fullWidth: fullWidth,
    ref: ref,
    required: required,
    color: color,
    variant: variant,
    ownerState: ownerState
  }, other, {
    children: [label != null && label !== '' && /*#__PURE__*/(0, _jsxRuntime.jsx)(_InputLabel.default, (0, _extends2.default)({
      htmlFor: id,
      id: inputLabelId
    }, InputLabelProps, {
      children: label
    })), select ? /*#__PURE__*/(0, _jsxRuntime.jsx)(_Select.default, (0, _extends2.default)({
      "aria-describedby": helperTextId,
      id: id,
      labelId: inputLabelId,
      value: value,
      input: InputElement
    }, SelectProps, {
      children: children
    })) : InputElement, helperText && /*#__PURE__*/(0, _jsxRuntime.jsx)(_FormHelperText.default, (0, _extends2.default)({
      id: helperTextId
    }, FormHelperTextProps, {
      children: helperText
    }))]
  }));

  
});
```

My question is purpose of double parenthesis after return statement. I know about case, where it possible when we execute a function which come as result of other function. But this is not same case. So what is this?

P.S. This is MUI React library, TextField.js

All information which i find in Google describe just case with invoke a function, which come from another one. But nothing about this case. This one is using so often in MUI React. So i need 2 know what is this.

Comment: It's just `(0, someFunction({ ... }))`, which is why there are two parentheses at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firts: what is it?** Its actually a function call "camouflaged". You see, parenthesis in JS usually mean calling a function, but when you have a list of expressions in parenthesis, it evaluates to the last one. So for example

```
("hello", "world") // evaluates to "world"

(1,2,3*4) // evaluates to 12
```

So basically Javascript ignores all elements except the last one and treats the whole parenthesis group as its last element

So what you are seing is basically is a function call

for example in the line:

```
className: (0, _clsx.default)(classes.root, className)
```

`_clsx.default` is a function, that is being called with the arguments `(classes.root, className)`. In other words this is equivalent to `_clsx.default(classes.root, className)`

Now you may be wondering... **why do they do that?**
Its result of the "compilation" or "transpilation" process that the app goes to. Because the library you are seeing is written in JSX (which is a syntax that allows javascript to handle HTML-like syntax for components), JSX needs to be converted into javascript, so its the "compiler" or "transpiler" that generates this code

You can see the actual code that generated those lines here
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/TextField/TextField.js
[image]

Comment: Precise explanation, thanks!